# Unable to grant DROP privilege on table to a role in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, privileges

I am trying to grant DROP privilege to a role with statement "GRANT DROP ON TABLE_NAME TO MY_ROLE_NAME".
But iam getting "missing or invalid privilege" error. I  have logged in as schema user to grant DROP privilege.

Can some one help me understand if it is syntax error or access issue or some other issue.

Comment: There is no such privilege as `drop` so you can't `grant drop`.  You normally wouldn't be creating and dropping tables dynamically so this normally wouldn't come up.  You could create a procedure owned by the schema owner that drops the table and grant the other user `execute` permission on this procedure.  That seems a bit over the top but perhaps that's worth it.

Comment: Also, system-level privileges can't be granted exclusively for specific objects. They tend to be all or nothing: e.g. "DROP *ANY* TABLE" privilege allows a user to drop any table in any schema. Unless you're the schema owner, you can't get more fine-grained than that, and the schema owner can - by definition - drop anything in it owns. The method proposed by @JustinCave is the only way to implement the kind of fine-grained approach you're talking about.