# Unable to Grant Drop, Alter privileges on a trigger to a role in oracle database

Tags: oracle, triggers, privileges

I want to grant DROP, ALTER privileges on a trigger to a role. I don't want to use "ANY" privileges as it leads to non-compliance. And, i want the roles to be granted on triggers in my schema.

Can some one help me with the syntax to achieve this. I didn't get any examples in google to do this.

Comment: I believe you can't do that.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same issue [as your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67321175/266304)? You can't do this via roles or privileges; you maybe could with a wrapper procedure, but... why would you want to? Why would you want anybody else to modify objects in your schema without your knowledge or involvement, whenever they want? If this is really about controlled updates to a non-user schema then look at proxy authentication, maybe.